# android studio fails to start showing internal error

Tags: android-studio

[error message on launching android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yxVE.png)

using "android-studio-2.1"

Everytime error message pops up on launching android studio but after restarting pc android studio opens up showing "gradle sync failed... protocol family unavailable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323700/android-studio-gradle-error-protocol-family-unavailable or several other questions -- if you searched the site before asking, let us know what didn't work.

Comment: What android studio version are you using? "android-studio-bundle-143.2915827-windows" isn't a version, it's the installer name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was proxifier issue. Turning off the proxifier worked but now it is showing error "failed to resolve junit:junit4.12".
I have tried uninstalling & installing, deleting .gradle folder and even adding these lines of code ...

```
android{
    repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

but it didn't worked