# "Protocol family unavailable " error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. I have installed it, but it shows "protocol family unavailable" error in every new project.
How do I fix that? Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Error - Protocol Family Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323700/android-studio-gradle-error-protocol-family-unavailable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution of that problem. If you use proxifier or any other software you use for  tunnel all TCP connections on the system or the selected ones only. Then take exit from that proxifier.      I hope your problem will fix.