# error in connecting gragle daemon

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Sorry there is no code.I have lost studio64.exe.vmoptions file so there is an error Error:Protocol family unavailable.I also search it on google but out of understanding. 
 Can you help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: can u explain me some more detail or any other way

Comment: The error 'Error:Protocol family unavailable'  occurs when i open any project.I also try [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323700/android-studio-gradle-error-protocol-family-unavailable)